# Vim: mouse support lost after using netrw in xterm

Tags: terminal, vim, mouse

Every time I access the filesystem using:

- `:tabe dirname` (e.g.: `:tabe .`)
- `:vsp dirname`
- `:sp dirname`

in order to open some file while editing another one, I lose the mouse support inside the Vim session.

I'm running **Vim 7.3.346** inside a fresh install of **Debian Wheezy**, using xterm.

I've tested with the minimal settings for Vim, for example with this `.vimrc`:

```
set nocp
set showmatch
set ts=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set foldmethod=syntax
syntax on
set autoindent
set smartindent
set mouse=a
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

Is there any solution, or a patch to a bug for this version of Vim?

---

**Update**:
At work this problem has never happened, the computers and servers we have are:

- Ubuntu 10.04.3, Vim 7.2.330
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11, Vim 7.2.108
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0, Vim 7.2.411

Should this be a problem of Vim 7.3?

Comment: If you issue `set mouse=a` again after such a "breaking command", can you use the mouse again or is it permanently broken?

Comment: No, it keeps on working without any response to the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still using version 7.3.346, then I found an useful setting:

```
set ttymouse=xterm2
```

with it, I haven't had the problem at least for a relatively short time of testing.

This bug was reported, and [should have been fixed with version 7.3.363-1](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg964458.html).

---

**UPDATE**:

Debian Wheezy has upgraded its version of Vim to 7.3.363, and the problem seems to be solved.